# Composite List-Hash Partitioning

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I was trying to change table from range-hash to list-hash  but it come difficult for me
Can you write example for this type of partitioning.

edit

actually i finally create something

```
create table T_COMPLEX
    (
        ID NUMBER,
        TIME_ID DATE
    )
    partition by LIST (TIME_ID) 
    SUBPARTITION BY HASH (ID)
    (
        partition k1 VALUES ('02-DEC-2002'),
        partition k2 VALUES ('17-APR-2003'),
        partition k3 VALUES ('15-OCT-2004'),
        partition k4 VALUES ('12-APR-2006')
    );
```

can u tell is it all fine here,mb i can modify this

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: look at edit i made

Comment: Do you really like to create **list** partition for a `DATE` value? I would rather suggest [interval partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-EC3C51AF-2F56-4617-A12B-4540D5C17F33.htm). Apart from that `'02-DEC-2002'` is not a `DATE` value, it is a string. Better use `DATE` literal (e.g. `DATE '2002-12-02'`) or `TO_DATE` function.

Comment: See [Creating Composite List-Hash Partitioned Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-E4131251-C76F-4DA0-8235-294C40F836B1.htm)

Comment: MANY thanks for advises